# (Laravel) check if today is between two dates based on a starting date

Tags: php, laravel, date, php-carbon

I have a payments table where I keep track of certain payments. Let's say I have a start date, which can be any date. Payments will have to be made each month.

For example, I want to track if a payment is due 5 days before it needs to be made. This will be checked on a daily basis. For this I use the following method:

```
public function isDue()
{
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $this->months; $i++) {

        if (Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d') >= Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $this->start)->addMonthsNoOverflow($i)->subDays(5)->format('Y-m-d')
            &&
            Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d') <= Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $this->start)->addMonthsNoOverflow($i)->format('Y-m-d')
        ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

`$this->start` is the starting date. `$this->months` means how many months a payment has to be made in total. So, using the for loop, the current date is being checked against the starting date.

My question basically is, since I want to make this foul proof, is there good way to accomplish this, or will something like a for loop and such work? The above code just feels sloppy to me and it will not produce the correct results I'm afraid.

Comment: You can [compare Carbon objects directly](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison) without worrying about formatting.

Comment: Thanks, I used to do that before with something else, not sure why I am making it so complicated now.. lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Carbon has a few other helper methods for comparison including `isToday()` that you can use:

```php
public function isDue()
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < $this->months; $i++) {
        if ($this->start_date->addMonthsNoOverflow($i)->subDays(5)->isToday()) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

This will create a loop for each month as you did before, and check that the adjusted date is today. If it is, the method immediately returns `true`.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, you want to check if the "start date plus few months" is between now and 5 days before now. In this case, you can do this:

```
if ($this->start->addMonthsNoOverflow($i)->between(now()->subDays(5), now()))
```

Comment: Thanks, will check out later if I can use it like this